# Accessing private field in distant parent class with reflection returns null

Tags: c#, reflection, xamarin.forms

I am trying access the private field of `_id` in [`Xamarin.Forms.Element`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Element.cs). Which is a distant parent of `Xamarin.Forms.Label`.

```
void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var label = new Label() { Text = "text" };
    var element = GetElement(label.GetType());
    var field = element.GetField("_id", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    var runtimeFields = element.GetRuntimeFields();
    var runtimeField = runtimeFields.First(f => f.Name == "_id");

    Console.WriteLine("label: " + field.GetValue(label));
    Console.WriteLine("runtime label: " + runtimeField.GetValue(label));
}
```

I am getting the Element base type with this method

```
private Type GetElement(Type type)
{
    if (type.Name != "Element")
    {
        return GetElement(type.BaseType);
    }
    return type;
}
```

I successfully get _id field and runtimeField - but calling `GetValue(label)` I get null. When setting a breakpoint and inspecting I can see that the `label` has a value for `_id` in `Xamarin.Forms.Element` BaseType. But that value does not write to console. Why?

---

When creating the label in xaml I still get null from the `_id` field.

```
<Label Text="text" x:Name="label"/>
```

And when setting a breakpoint I can see that `_id` field has a value.

Comment: Does the breakpoint inspector itself call the get property `Id` - setting the `_id` field?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772870/c-sharp-propery-getter-automatically-called-when-debugging-for-passive-propert

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why would you even need `GetElement(Type)` to get the type of an element. `typeof(Element)` would work just fine. So, to get your field, you need `FieldInfo idField = typeof(Element).GetField("_id", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)`, and to get its value, use `idField.GetValue(label)`. That would definitely give you object's `_id`.

P.S from the way the code in the question is written, I presumed that you're handling some label's clicked event. I'm not sure when does `_id` field get initialized but it may does only after it's added to a parent; and you're getting the `_id` value from the label you just created instead of using the `sender` parameter. If I presumed right, you may want to use `GetValue(sender)` instead of `GetValue(label)`.

Comment: I see I thought I had to get the type from the object. But I can simply take the type directly with `typeof(Element)`.

Comment: I am investigating this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56405488/cant-create-content-with-datatemplate-in-code-behind-with-control-defined-in-xa#comment99434525_56405488. The event handler is assigned to a button - just for testing.